# I am trying to pass letters through ajax to get the first letter of a lastName and link it to the navbar, wrong code?

Tags: php, jquery

I am building a contacts directory (see picture).

[image]

On the right there is a nav bar with the alphabet.
At the moment all the contacts from the database are showing but what I am trying to do is to only show the ones where the lastName starts by the letter clicked on the nav bar and hide the rest.

So basically when I click to, for example letter B on the nav bar on the right, I want all the contacts with last names starting by the letter B to appear instead of all of the contacts, does this make sense?

I have been suggested to wrap each name into the letter they start with however I have a very large database and I am not really sure how to apply that on php. This is what I have come up with so far.

I have tried this now but not sure where I am going wrong. I think it is in the php when I am trying to implement the sql "like" operator in javascript as I'm probably not using the right method but please if someone could tell me where am I going wrong would be great!

I know I need to use something similar to this but not sure how to apply it:

```
 $('#nav a').click(function (e) {
      var str = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
      for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
          var nextChar = str.charAt(i);
          $('#' + nextChar).fadeOut();
      }
      var txt = $(e.target).text();
      $('#' + txt).delay(400).fadeIn();
  });
```

Or something like:

```
.click $('.')this $this.id and pass letter on ajax
```

See my code here:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'php/getAll.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data, alphabet, sort) {
      alphabet = data.nav;
      var db = data.data;
       for (var letter of alphabet) {
            $("#nav").append(`<li><a href="?firstLetter=${letter}">${letter}</a></li>`); 
        }
      for (let i in db) {
        $('#database').append(`
                <div class="loadProfile col-sm-6 col-md-4" onclick="loadProfile(${JSON.stringify(db[i]).split('"').join("&quot;")})">
                <div class="widget col-3 profile">
                    <div class="widget-simple">
                        <span>
                        <img src="img/user-regulars.svg" alt="avatar" class="widget-image img-circle pull-left animation-fadeIn">
                        </span>
                            <h4 class="widget-content text-left">
                                <span id="fullName">${db[i].lastName}, ${db[i].firstName}</span>
                                <p class="findID" style="font-size:11px; color: rgb(190, 190, 190); display: inline"> - ID: ${db[i].id}</p>
                                <br>
                                <div class="info" style: "overflow: hidden">
                                    <p class=${filterBy == "department"} style="font-size:11px; color: rgb(190, 190, 190); float: left">${db[i].department}</p>
                                    <p class=${filterBy == "location"} style="font-size:11px; color: rgb(190, 190, 190); float: left">, ${db[i].location}</p>
                                    <a href="" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary2 Phone" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="Phone"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i></a>
                                    <a href="mailto:${db[i].email}" rel="prefetch" id="eM" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary Email" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="Email"><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i></a>
                                </div>
                            </h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                `)
      }
      return true;
    }
  })
})
```

HTML:

```
<main>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 main">
        <div class="block1">
          <div id="nav" class="CharacterContainer"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row style-alt" id="database">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
<?php
$sort = isset($_GET['firstLetter']) ? filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'firstLetter',FILTER_SANITIZE_URL) : "" ; 
    $query = "SELECT p.id, p.lastName, p.firstName, p.jobTitle, p.email, d.name as department, l.name as location FROM personnel p LEFT JOIN department d ON (d.id = p.departmentID) LEFT JOIN location l ON (l.id = d.locationID) WHERE p.lastName LIKE '$sort%' ORDER BY p.lastName ASC" ;
    $result = $conn->query($query);
 <?
```

Comment: This is at least the third time I see you asking about this today. Why are you constantly removing the existing questions, and asking again?

Comment: PS: `$('#database').append` in a for loop - is a bad idea. Concatenate in memory and than append only once.

Comment: _“Because I need an answer”_ - how is that a justification for deleting and re-asking all the time? It is not. So please stop doing that, thank you.

Comment: Also, it makes no sense to send the entire contacts data to the frontend in the first place - waste of bandwith - for than searching by Character... something the frontend already has.

Comment: Also, open your phone, see how a contact search works. It returns all the contacts that have those character**s** (begins-with /or in other apps/ anywhere) in the name + middlename + surname fields... - And it's not only by first letter. - So basically there's one single function that does all that job: Single or multiple letters.

Comment: Thank you @RokoC.Buljan for the suggestion! I know it works like that but I am doing something specific that requires to search only by first letter of surname.

I am not trying to do the contact search bar but the nav where you have all the letters and you pres let's say B and then all the contacts with surname starting with letter B appear.

Comment: Now the question still remains. If you already sent all the necessary data to the frontend - why don't you do the filtering on the frontend part?

Comment: Because I don't know how to do it

Comment: Unrelated to current question but `FILTER_SANITIZE_URL` won't help with SQL injection. Should parameterize query and use prepared statement. (The last `<?` also is a typo, should be `?>` but presuming this is pseudo code anyway)

Comment: _"I have been suggested to wrap each name into the letter they start with..."_ - and you've been suggested well. Take the wrapping element for a contact, place a data attribute with the starting letter in it and then you can filter on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.each` loop to iterate through your `loadProfile` div and then get value of `fullName` span then split that text using `split(",")[0]` here `0` will give you value before commas(lastname) . Then use that to see if the first letter matches with `a` tag text then show that divs else hide .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //suppose data look like this
  var data = {
    "nav": ["A", "B", "All"],
    "data": [{
      "lastName": "Abc",
      "firstName": "avcd"
    }, {
      "lastName": "Bbc",
      "firstName": "avcd"
    }, {
      "lastName": "Abc",
      "firstName": "avcd"
    }]
  }
  alphabet = data.nav;
  var db = data.data;
  for (var letter of alphabet) {
    $("#nav").append(`<li><a href="?firstLetter=${letter}">${letter}</a></li>`);
  }
  for (let i in db) {
    $('#database').append(`
                <div class="loadProfile col-sm-6 col-md-4" onclick="loadProfile(${JSON.stringify(db[i]).split('"').join("&quot;")})">
                <div class="widget col-3 profile">
                    <div class="widget-simple">
                        <span>
                        <img src="img/user-regulars.svg" alt="avatar" class="widget-image img-circle pull-left animation-fadeIn">
                        </span>
                            <h4 class="widget-content text-left">                        
                                <span class="fullName">${db[i].lastName}, ${db[i].firstName}</span>
                               
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                `)
  }
})

$('#nav').on('click', 'a', function(e) {
  //get a tag text
  var to_search = $(this).text().toLowerCase().trim()
  e.preventDefault()
  if (to_search != "all") {
    $(".loadProfile").hide() //hide all divs
    //loop through divs
    $(".loadProfile .fullName").each(function() {
      //get last name by using split 
      var value = $(this).text().toLowerCase().trim().split(",")[0]
      //check if char at `0` positon matchs with to_searc
      if (value.charAt(0) == to_search) {
        $(this).closest(".loadProfile").delay(400).fadeIn(); //show same
      }
    })
  } else {
    $(".loadProfile").delay(400).fadeIn();

  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="database"></div>
<div id="nav"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

For reference / completeness, here's how to wrap each group and show by group.

When creating the list in php in the first place, sort by last name, then check the first letter, if it's the different from the previous person's name, add a new section.

Alternatively, the same js code will work if you have

```
<div data-index='${substr(db[i].lastName, 0, 1)}'>
    <span ... user details
```

```js
$("#index>button").click(function() { 
    var idx = $(this).text();
    $("[data-index]").hide();
    $("[data-index=" + idx + "]").show();
});
```

```css
h1 { font-size: 1.5em; border-top:1px solid #CCC }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="index">
  <button type='button'>A</button>
  <button type='button'>B</button>
  <button type='button'>C</button>
</div>

<div data-index='A'>
  <h1>A</h1>
  <!-- doesn't matter how these are formatted -->
  User A1
  <br/> User A2
</div>
<div data-index='B'>
  <h1>B</h1>
  <!-- doesn't matter how these are formatted -->
  <ul>
    <li>User B1</li>
    <li>User B2</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div data-index='C'>
  <h1>C</h1>
  <!-- doesn't matter how these are formatted -->
  <ul>
    <li>User B1</li>
    <li>User B2</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```